# How to scrape Title and Price (Beautifulsoup)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get all the album names and prices from this website: https://vinilosalvaro.cl/tienda/

But with the following script I'm just getting one of them.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = 'https://vinilosalvaro.cl/tienda/'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3'}
page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
listado_productos = soup.find_all('ul', class_='products columns-3')

for listado_productos in listado_productos:
  titulos = listado_productos.find('h2', class_='woocommerce-loop-product__title').text.strip()
  precios = listado_productos.find('span', class_='woocommerce-Price-amount amount').text.strip()
  print(titulos)
  print(precios)
```

How to get all the album names and prices?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `find_all` you can use `find` when searching for one specific `ul` tags. go ahead and change line 10 to:

```
listado_productos = soup.find('ul', class_='products columns-3')
```

Also, to get `li` childs, you should use `find_all('li')`, so change the line 12 to:

```
for listado_productos in listado_productos.find_all('li'):
```

Answer (score 0):

Main issue is that your selection give you a `ResultSet` of one `<ul>` not all the `<li>` so your loop just iterate one time.

Select your Elements more specific as also mentioned @benyamin payandeh or for example with [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
soup.select('ul.products li')
```

In addition also some concepts like `while loop` for paging, `.get_text(strip=True)` and how to store your results over iterations in a more structured form like a `list` of `dicts` that you can simply transform in `dataframes` or process like you need.

###### Example

*Be aware this will start from page 59, to show how the while loop works and break if there is no more page to scrape. Simply set `URL` to your default value to iterate all pages*

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://vinilosalvaro.cl/tienda/page/59/'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3'}

data = []

while True:
    page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    for listado_productos in soup.select('ul.products li'):
        data.append({
            'titulos' : listado_productos.h2.get_text(strip=True),
            'precios' : listado_productos.span.get_text(strip=True)
        })
    
    if soup.select_one('a.next'):
        URL = soup.select_one('a.next').get('href')
    else:
        break
data
```